# Long math equation needs to be displayed in a nice manner

Tags: math-mode

I'd appreciate if you can assist me with re-arranging the following for getting better form in order to display this long equation.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\rho \epsilon {\bf \ddot u_{0}(v},t)=\epsilon \int_{\mathcal{R}} f(\eta_{00},\xi_{00})dA'+\\
    \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 \int_{\mathcal{R}} \left( \big [\frac{\partial \bf f}{\partial \eta}(\eta_{00},\xi_{00}) \big]{\bf a'(v},t)+\big [\frac{\partial \bf f}{\partial \xi}(\eta_{00},\xi_{00})]k \right )dA'
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site :) I think it would really be best to ask the second question separately (assuming the question isn't already answered somewhere on the site) as the two parts are quite unrelated. The best advice I can give you is that Stackexchange is not a forum, or bulletin board, or help centre, but a Q & A site which aims to be a repository of information on various topics. So it's best to have a question just about linking to equations, and a question just about equation breaking, and then the info can be concentrated and others with the same Q can find the info more easily

Comment: Also, please provide a complete small document we can copy-paste-compile. For example, it matters what the current `\linewidth` is and that obviously depends on the class and any packages or settings which adjust the paper size or layout dimensions. Also, don't use commands such as `\bf` in LaTeX as they are 20+ years deprecated. (Was this ever correct in maths mode? Maybe. I am quite ignorant of those times.)

Comment: @ Au101I  edited the question.

Comment: @ cfr sure. \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

Comment: That cannot be compiled. It lacks a `document` environment and it does not initiate maths mode. I get errors when I copy, paste and try to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `align*` environment to display the two-line equation.

[image]

Note that I've enlarged the square brackets in the second line. I've also replaced various `{\bf ...}` constructs with `\mathbf{...}` directives.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\rho \epsilon \ddot{\mathbf{u}}_{0}(\mathbf{v},t)
&=\epsilon \int_{\mathcal{R}} f(\eta_{00},\xi_{00})\,dA'\\
&\quad+\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 \int_{\mathcal{R}} 
\biggl( \biggl[ \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \eta}(\eta_{00},\xi_{00}) \biggr]\mathbf{a}'(\mathbf{v},t)+
\biggl[ \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \xi}(\eta_{00},\xi_{00})\biggr]k \biggr) \,dA'
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico, the equation number is disappeared after your change? why?

Comment: @Mohammad - You didn't indicate in your posting that you need the equation to be numbered. If you need a numbered equation, change `align*` to `align` and add `\notag` before the end of the first line.

Comment: @ Mico, it does work. Can I use to \label{eq:#} in front of align in order to cite the equation in text? Thanks for time.

Comment: @Mohammad -  Not *before* `\begin{align}`, but on the line you want to be numbered.

Answer (score 4):

If you also want a reference, you could instead use the `split` environment provided by **amsmath** inside an `equation`:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{e:myeqn}
  \begin{split}
    \rho \epsilon \mathbf{\ddot u_{0}(v},t)={} &\epsilon \int_{\mathcal{R}} f(\eta_{00},\xi_{00})dA'+\\
    &\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 \int_{\mathcal{R}} \left( \bigg [\frac{\partial \mathbf{f} }{\partial \eta}(\eta_{00},\xi_{00}) \bigg]\mathbf{a'(v},t)+\bigg [\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \xi}(\eta_{00},\xi_{00})\bigg]k \right )dA'
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
We can now refer to equation \eqref{e:myeqn}.
\end{document}
```

[image: long equation with cross-reference]

EDITED to incorporate Mico's and [daleif's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290307/long-math-equation-needs-to-be-displayed-in-a-nice-manner/290312?noredirect=1#comment702487_290312) corrections.

Comment: what is the difference between split & align..since both give same result. Is it not?

Comment: @cfr you might want to use `={}  & `, look at the space after =

Comment: @Mohammad split is sort of an inner construction case it has to be used inside an existing math construction. It does not add line numbers, so you can get a single number for the entire multi line construction. Split supports a single alignment block, ie at most one `&` per line. Personally I use `aligned` or `alignedat` a lot more as they support multiple alignment blocks, plus they start in the middle of the page, not at the left edge (as I think `split` does),tjis can save vertical space when combined with the `equation` env